# Not treating empty cells as zero

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a function to do linear interpolation:

```
Public Function linear_interpolation(xs As Range, ys As Range, x As Double)
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim x0 As Double, x1 As Double
    Dim y0 As Double, y1 As Double
    index = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(x, xs)
    x0 = xs(index)
    y0 = ys(index)
    x1 = xs(index + 1)
    y1 = ys(index + 1)
    linear_interpolation = ((x1 - x) * y0 + (x - x0) * y1) / (x1 - x0)
End Function
```

It works fine if both ranges `xs` and `ys` are fully populated, but if there is a missing value (empty cell) then it is treated as a zero, which is surprising, I was expecting a type error. If the cell contains a non-numerical value, then I get `#VALUE!` as expected.

What's the best way of dealing with this? Do I have to manually check to see if `xs(index)`, `ys(index)`, `xs(index+1)` and `ys(index+1)` empty and then return an error?

Comment: is `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(x, xs)` always returning a match to `index` ? if not I would deal with the possible error of `Match`

Comment: @ShaiRado: xs might not be missing any values, but ys could

Comment: You can eiter trap `xs` and/or `ys` but then again, does it matter to you which one ? you just care what is the result of `linear_interpolation` , so you can set a trap for it, with `On Error Resume Next` and add a rule

Comment: @ShaiRado: I'm not sure what trapping means so I might be misinterpreting your response. My issue is that in the above code, line 7, y0 is set to zero, but I would like an error to occur instead.

Comment: you can always do `If y0 = 0 Then MsgBox "Error"` and `Exit Function`, or `If y0 = 0 Then linear_interpolation = CVErr(xlErrNA)` (return #NA) , and then `Exit Function`

Comment: @ShaiRado: yes, thank you. I'm aware of this solution, and it would have to involve checking `xs(index)`, `xs(index+1)` and `ys(index+1)` as well in general (as noted in my question). On a side note: my problem isn't when `y0 = 0`, that could be perfectly legitimate behaviour, but rather when `ys(index)` is an empty cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123059/discussion-between-shai-rado-and-user357269).

Comment: I think you'd better act over the _original_  source range and set/filter it properly so as to pass valid x-y ranges only to your linear_interpolation()

Answer (score 0):

If you still need 0 in the cell but wan to flag error for NULL or "" you could easily involve a check that says

```
IF cell.value = VBNullString Then
    'do some stuff
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

No sense reinventing the wheel! There's a [linear interpolation function](http://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/powerful-excel-linear-interpolation-function-vba/) on my website - *I apologize for the shameless plug* - that grabs the nearest values to the value you're trying to interpolate on so you don't have to worry about the empty cells registering as zeros:)

Bottom line is you want to add a check for the values equal to an empty string ""

Source: http://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/powerful-excel-linear-interpolation-function-vba/